# ARM NEON Intrinsics: Limit values of a vector to 0-255

Tags: c, arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

Say I have an `int16x8_t` vector. I want to limit the range of its values to 0-255 and convert it to an `uint8x8_t` vector. Reading the vector into an array and doing it the traditional non-intrinsic way is waaaay too slow. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the single instruction `vqmovun.s16`, `vqmovun_s16` in intrinsics.

Vector Saturating(q) Move Unsigned Narrow

```
int16x8_t input;
uint8x8_t result;
.
.
.
.
.
.

result = vqmovun_s16(input);
```

Any negative element will be replaced with 0 while all the numbers bigger than 255 will be set as 255 then narrowed to unsigned 8bit elements, and all these in a single cycle, EXACTLY what you need.

There is also `vqmovn_s16` which keeps the values signed (-128~127)

PS: Are you working on YUV to RGB conversion? That's the one time I needed this instruction.

Comment: Thank you! Nope, I'm just doing normal image convolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found a way. It's still quite slow but it works:

```
int16x8_t q_result;
int16x8_t max_value = vdupq_n_s16(255);
int16x8_t min_value = vdupq_n_s16(0);
uint16x8_t max_mask, min_mask;
max_mask = vcgtq_s16(q_result, max_value);
min_mask = vcltq_s16(q_result, min_value);
q_result = vbslq_s16(max_mask, max_value, q_result);
q_result = vbslq_s16(min_mask, min_value, q_result);
```

Comment: You’re over-complicating it - just use `vmaxq_s16`/`vminq_s16`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `vmaxq_s16`/`vminq_s16`:

```
const int16x8_t max_value = vdupq_n_s16(255);
const int16x8_t min_value = vdupq_n_s16(0);
int16x8_t q_result = ...;
q_result = vmaxq_s16(min_value, q_result);
q_result = vminq_s16(max_value, q_result);
```